# urlopen, BeautifulSoup and UTF-8 Issue

Tags: python, utf-8, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I am just trying to retrieve a web page, but somehow a foreign character is embedded in the HTML file. This character is not visible when I use "View Source."

```
isbn = 9780141187983
url = "http://search.barnesandnoble.com/booksearch/isbninquiry.asp?ean=%s" % isbn
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
url_opener = opener.open(url)
page = url_opener.read()
html = BeautifulSoup(page) 
html #This line causes error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 21555: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I also tried...

```
html = BeautifulSoup(page.encode('utf-8'))
```

How can I read this web page into BeautifulSoup without getting this error?

Comment: Would you mind giving the actual url?

Comment: Done. Was trying to avoid making code more verbose. :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this; works fine here. I have retrieved the url using your code several times, and there never was a non-ASCII character in the page.

Comment: however balpha, you don't want to rely on that and have a remote URL changing content making your applications crash. As a rule, remote URLs always change.

Comment: @kaizer.se: I'm totally with you on that, but the first thing to remove bugs is trying to reproduce them.

Comment: it would be interesting to get a complete traceback: the one you are giving is not helpful :) Also, what version of BS are you running?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error is probably actually happening when you try to *print* the representation of the BeautifulSoup file, which will happen automatically if, as I suspect, you are working in the interactive console.

```
# This code will work fine, note we are assigning the result 
# of the BeautifulSoup object to prevent it from printing immediately.
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(u'\xa0')

# This will probably show the error you saw
print soup

# And this would probably be fine
print soup.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is correct. The error was encountered when trying to debug and printing the content to the screen. It is unfortunate that UTF-8 issues make debugging such a challenge, but the code does work correctly as long as I do not print.

Comment: @Ryan - Trust me - I've been there.  Glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following :

```
import codecs 
f = codecs.open(filename,'r','utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"html.parser")
```

I encountered a similar problem with bs4